# Is it possible to launch (redirect the user to) the native photo gallery application of iphone from my app,

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is it possible to launch (redirect the user to) the native photo gallery application not sms or phone of iphone from my app,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that would have been a custom URL scheme but AFAIK there is no schemes for the photo app.
[See here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007891-SW1) the existing custom URL schemes for native iOS apps.

If you want to display the user's photos, you can use either:
-the UIImagePickerController (you'll find tutorials on the web) or
-the ALAssetsLibrary to access the photos and videos (that's a lot more work as you will have to create the GUI to display the photos yourself). [See here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `photos-redirect://` URL scheme with `openURL:` like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"photos-redirect://"]];
```

... as pointed out in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564019/how-can-i-show-last-saved-photo-in-photos-app-ios-via-photos-redirect-url-sch). Bear in mind, that it's not a public URL scheme and may cause rejection from App Store.

Comment: Does anyone know if this can be used to open a said PHAsset in the app? I'm thinking specifying the localidentifier as parameter.