# How can I show last saved photo in Photos app iOS via "photos-redirect:" URL scheme?

Tags: ios

When I use `photos-redirect://` URL scheme it just starts Photos app.

How can I start Photos app with showing custom photo, for example, last saved?
I can't find any examples, where used `photos-redirect://` URL scheme.

Comment: It's not a public scheme. You may be able to find some resource form someone who's puzzled something out, but it's not going to be guaranteed to work. You can actually get these images from the assets framework if you need to show them for some reason, although you'd have to write the GUI and the backend for this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

`photos-redirect://` is the URL Scheme for Photo App. However, it is undocumented, thus you shouldn't use it.

To view / select a photo, use `UIImagePickerController` .

Comment: You mean UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Hey Raptor, why exactly shouldn't we use that method?

Comment: Apps using undocumented / private methods will probably be rejected by Apple approval.