# how can I show selected image in Photos app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, native

currently in my app I'm fetching the images from Photos app and showing them in my app.
in my app when user click the image
I want to open Photos app with selected image ,is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show last saved photo in Photos app iOS via "photos-redirect:" URL scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564019/how-can-i-show-last-saved-photo-in-photos-app-ios-via-photos-redirect-url-sch)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.
Also, There is not officially documented way to open Photos App as well.
You might, still open the Photos application using `photos-redirect://` url scheme but this is also not documented by Apple to use so you might face some problems with it during the review process.
Opening to certain pre-selected photo in the Photos application is not possible.