# How can I jump to Photos app by a specific image's identifier on my App?

Tags: swift, uiapplication, phasset, phimagemanager

This question is similar to [how can I show selected image in the Photos app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124200/how-can-i-show-selected-image-in-photos-app).  I'm writing a photo gallery app that loads photos from `Photos` using `PHImageManager.requestImage()`, so for a specific low-quality image(usually `CGSize(width: 256, height: 256)`) shows on my App, I could get all the information of it's `PHAsset`, such as `identifier`.

From that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124200/how-can-i-show-selected-image-in-photos-app), I know it may not be possible to allow the user clicking the image to open Photos with the selected image.  Actually there is another way of using `PHImageManager.requestImage()` to fetch HQ images, such as:

```swift
photoCollection.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 1024))
```

However, this will fetch the original image from iCloud, but my app is designed for `No Network Needed`.

The key point is to **make the user can quickly find the original photo** from the Photos, so maybe the underwriting solution is: to show the `Date` of that image on the screen, so the user can go back to Photos and locate that photo by date, anyone have a better solution?