# Open gallery from app in swift

Tags: ios, swift4

I wan't to let the user open the iPhone's gallery.

I do **NOT** need the user to pick a photo nor a video and come back to my app, I am aware that i can achieve this using the `UIImagePickerController`. What I want is that the iOS gallery app is opened and set active.

As said in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728854/is-it-possible-to-launch-another-app-in-ios-8-using-swift), i know you can use other apps using `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)` with the correct url, does it exist a url that I can use for this or is there another method? thanks!.

Comment: have you upload app on app-store with "photos-redirect://" URL Scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure what you mean by « gallery », but if what you’re looking for is opening the Photos app, you may try with this URL: **photos-redirect://**
Be aware that this is not a publicly documented URL scheme so maybe Apple will not accept its use and may reject your app during review...

Sources: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/ and [Is it possible to launch (redirect the user to) the native photo gallery application of iphone from my app,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547214/is-it-possible-to-launch-redirect-the-user-to-the-native-photo-gallery-applica)